# CMS track & trace tool

Tags: wordpress, joomla, content-management-system, e-commerce, virtuemart

I'm developing website for freight(cargo) forwarding/logistics company.
It will be CMS based (Joomla or Wordpress). What I need is component/plugin (can be commercial)
that has this functionality: (doesnt have to work exactly this way)
It can be simple e-commerce/virtuemart extension, whatever that is close.

1. Client logs in
2. Adds his tracking number(cargo/order number whatever)
3. He will see his his cargo status and current place.

Cargo status can be managed manually in CMS backend via admin.

Doesn't have to work exactly this way, but basic idea is this.

Comment: Requests for recommendations for plugins are not considered on-topic (even on the Wordpress.SE).

Answer (score 2):

It does not matter joomla or wordpress these are the things you have to do.

Before You Start, Solidify Your Business Goals:

Do you fully understand the business outcome and goals that you’re trying to accomplish? Do you understand how you're going to measure the success of your implementation? Example: sales & marketing metrics.

Quick Qualification:

Does the extension work for your Joomla version? Is the extension in the expected category? How popular is the extension brand name? What is the extension type (Component, Module, Plugin)? Do you a long and short list of your possible extension choices? Does the extension meet your hosting requirements? Is the extension GPL? Is the extension encoded? Are some or all files encoded? What is the extension rating score on the official Joomla resource directory? What is the number of ratings? What's the extension popularity and number of downloads?

Critical Features to Meet Business Objectives:

Feature A) < Enter your specific feature requirement here > Feature B) < Enter your specific feature requirement here > Feature C) < Enter your specific feature requirement here > Feature D) < Enter your specific feature requirement here > Feature E) < Enter your specific feature requirement here >

Other Secondary Features:

Do you understand the total list of features you need (captcha type, ability to embed in articles, database storage, confirmations, styling options, …) Does it unnecessarily complicates the site installation (example: job extension and you have only 3-4 jobs)?

Security Concerns / Scam-Like Internet Practices:

Do you understand security issues and problems related to installing this extensions? Can developers/company be trusted? What's the company online reputation? Are their extensions listed in the Joomla extensions directory? How long has the extension existed? Does the extension contain or require backlinks? Are their hidden links? Ads inserted in the control panel or front end? Does the extension contain call home functions? They're only welcomed if the extension can work normally without a developer server connection, it is possible to install it without call home and it only calls home for the version check. Does the public version of the extension contain security risks? Is it listed in the vulnerable extension list?

Legal/Licensing

Does it limit use per domain/installation? Does it limit distribution of extension? Does it require a nondisclosure agreement? Does it limit usage of non GPL media files to a domain/installation? Is the extension not listed at JED? Does it limit support per domain/installation? Does it require payment to remove owner visible or hidden links?

User Experience

Does it offer professional user experience for the site visitors? What is the website administrator user experience?

SEO

Does the extension follow the best industry SEO practices? Does the extension support search engine friendly URLs?

Community

Does the extension have a solid and favorable community view?

Demo

Is there a demo or light version?

Author / Company

What's the extension website? Who is the developer or development team? What's the extension roadmap? Is the official extension easy to download? Are there FAQs, written tutorials and training available?

Test Installation

Do you have a test installation ready to evaluate an extension before trying it on your test installation?

Initial Set Up

Do you understand how to set up test installation, have time, resources, knowledge, experience, etc? Do you have to manually copy extension files for it to install?

Maintenance

Will the extension be easy to maintain? Is the extension easy to update? When was the last version released? Are security patches being promptly published? What is the stage of the extension development? Does the extension modify Joomla core files? Do you must have file/folder permissions set to 777 to install & run? After the extension is uninstalled, does the site or admin return errors? Does the extension team offer good technical support?

Cost

Is the extension free/commercial? Does the plugin require one time payment or membership subscription?

Read more on [How to choose a Joomla! Extensions](http://khmerjoomla.org/tutorial/joomla-artilces/37-joomla-tutorial/75-how-to-choose-a-joomla-extensions.html)

Comment: I have already concerned this questions, I need direct answers, not this. Thanks

Comment: you should start googling then. I don't think you will be able to find a direct answer here. Hope for the best. :-)

Comment: I googled, however didn't find anything. The component doesn't have to exactly fit freight forwarding company it can be basic e-commerce plugin but with funtionality explained above. We will see, there might be people who know, thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

If you end up using Joomla, look into extension called Fabrik - http://www.fabrikar.com , that will give you an ability to maintain a list of custom defined entries (database table) and give the end-user ability to search through it (filter by individual fields). You can restrict which records (shipments) are visible to each user based on their username, etc.

I've created a few Web sites for freight forwarders, including cargo tracking sites and one thing I can say for sure - if they already use a TMS (Transportation Management System) where they already have tracking / status information they won't like the idea of double-entering it in another system.  Fabrik is easily configurable to connect to external databases if this data is available elsewhere and tracking it there in real time.

Watch their tutorials, it is really powerful. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks "Watch Insiders" I ended up using fabrikar, I see you have quite an experience with it, I have just one question, is it possible to create a fabrikar form, where u will enter your query (example:Cargo ID) and it will show you results based on the logged user? Something like tracking form, thanks

Comment: My apologies, I didn't see your question until just now. The short answer is yes. Look into pre-filtering and use their profile user ID to narrow down the results to their own entries only.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with any of the well rated forms components for Joomla, which you can find at http://extensions.joomla.org